# inserting a number from stdout into a string from stdout

Tags: linux, shell

I'm working on a Linux terminal.
I have a string followed by a number as stdout and I need a command that replaces the middle of the string by the number and writes the result to stdout.

This is the string and number: librarian 16
and this is what the output should be: l16n

I have tried using `echo librarian 16|sed s/[a-z]*/16/g` and this gives me 9 999 the problems are that it replaces every letter separitaly and that it also replaces the first and last letter and that I can't make it use the number from stdout.

I have also tried using `cut -c 1-1`  ,  `sed s/[^0-9]*//g`  and  `cut-c 9-9`  to generate l, 16 and n respectively but I can't find how to combine their outputs into a single line.

Lastly I have tried using text editors to copy the number and paste it into the string but I haven't made much progress since I don't know how to use editors directly from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is to **capture** the first letter, the last letter and the number while ignoring the middle.

In regex we use  `(` and `)` to tell the engine what we want to capture, anything else simply gets matched, or "eaten", but not captured. So the pattern should look like this:

```
([a-z])[a-z]*([a-z]) ([0-9]+)
```

- `([a-z])` to capture the first letter
- `[a-z]*` to match zero or more characters but *not capture*. We choose "*" here because there might not be anything to match in the middle, like when there are two or less letters.
- `([a-z])` to capture the last letter.
- to "eat" the whitespace.
- `([0-9]+)` to capture the number. We use `+` instead of `*` because we **require** a number at this position.

`sed` uses a different syntax for some fo these constructs so we'll use the `-E` flag. You could do without it but you'd have to escape the `()+` characters which IMO makes pattern a little bit confusing.

Now, to retrieve the captured content, we have to use an engine-specific sequence of characters. `sed` uses `\n` where n is the number of the capturing group, so our final pattern should look like this:

```
\1\3\2
```

- `\1`: First letter
- `\3`: Number
- `\2`: Last letter

Now we put everything together:

```sh
$ echo librarian 16|sed -r 's/([a-z])[a-z]*([a-z]) ([0-9]+)/\1\3\2/g'
l16n
```